# Trying to ask for an integer input based on user

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, integer, console-application

Vb.net how to ask a user for an integer? That’s how many times they have to input a number and then find the largest number

Can’t think of the logic

Comment: Ask the user to input a string, then try to convert it to an integer using [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse)

Comment: @KlausGütter can you help me with a pseudo code in vbnet please?

Comment: The logic doesn't take any programming experience at all. The logic is the same as you'd use to do it manually. I have little doubt that you could do it manually so I have little doubt that you could think of the logic. You just don't want to. It's the implementation part that is a programming problem and if you don't have the logic yet then you're not at the implementation part.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i think im asking for the pseudo code coz I’m not thinking of any logic that needs to be implemented. That’s why im asking for help even if its only a pseudo code. If you dont want to help, its ok. Im just really stuck at the point where i have to ask a user for an integer and have that integer the number of times where im going to ask the user to input number. Im not asking for a full code here but just for a guidance

Comment: Ask User to enter a string, then convert the string to integer, and use a loop to traverse the integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Print("Please enter count")
Dim input As String = ReadFromUser()
Dim count As Integer = ConvertToInteger(input)
Dim numbers(count - 1) As Integer
For i = 0 To count - 1
    input = ReadFromUser()
    Dim n As Integer = ConvertToInteger(input)
    numbers(i) = n
Next
Sort(numbers)
```